# How to position the Qwidget form/QDialogBox in the left corner using python programming

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qt, pyqt

1) I am creating a Qwidget Form or QDialogBox using QT Designer. I am using the following code to move the form:

```
sDialog.move(50,450)
```

But i want to fit the dialogBox to fit in the left corner.How can i do that using Python programming?

2) When i am using the Canvas events if i click on the map dialogBox/Form is hiding but i want to fit the position so if we do any thing on the map also the DialogBox should nt hide.How can i do that using python programming?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll answer the question that is stated in the title.

You can use the following code to show your dialog in the bottom-left corner (do all this right before the call to `self.dlg.show()`):

```
    ph = self.dlg.parent().geometry().height()
    px = self.dlg.parent().geometry().x()
    py = self.dlg.parent().geometry().y()
    dw = self.dlg.width()
    dh = self.dlg.height()   
    self.dlg.setGeometry( px, py+ph-dh, dw, dh )
```

If you want your dialog at the top-left corner, change the second parameter of `setGeometry()` to `py`.

As for your second question, I cannot replicate that. Have a look at my plugin [Synchronize QGIS with a directory](http://websvn.tuxfamily.org/filedetails.php?repname=tuxgis%2Fgeotux&path=%2Ftrunk%2FSyncQGISWithDir%2Fsyncqgiswithdir.py), the dialog is not hidden when I interact with the map via map tools.

---

By the way, you should really ask a single question per post. Otherwise you discourage people to answer your questions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But i am using this method also to position the dialog but i want to fit box in the main window itself.How can i do that?    offset_x = 50
offset_y = 450
sDialog.setGeometry(offset_x, offset_y, 212, 190)

Comment: Thanks @gcarrillo your plugin reference has solved my issue. Thank u so much